# Access VBA Create a Temporary Query in SQL that another SQL query uses

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a question about running SQL within Access VBA.  I want to basically create a query in vba but not have it be a query in my database.  It just sits there, invisible, until an operation using it is complete, and then it erases.

My code is below (simplified to focus on this issue).  I don't think I'm doing this right because I think on the 2nd query I need to do the `" & ECStart2SQL & "` thing, but I don't know how it will work when I need to reference a value.

```
Private Sub TimeReportingButton_Click()
'THIS IS THE 1ST QUERY
Dim ECStart2SQL As String
ECStart2SQL = "SELECT D1.[#], (SELECT Count(*) FROM tbl_Data D2 WHERE D2.[#] = D1.[#] AND D2.[tsUpdated] <= D1.[tsUpdated]) AS Sequence, D1.tsUpdated FROM tbl_Data AS D1 WHERE ((((SELECT Count(*) FROM tbl_Data D2 WHERE D2.[#] = D1.[#] AND D2.[tsUpdated] <= D1.[tsUpdated]))=1)) ORDER BY D1.[#]"


'THIS IS THE 2ND QUERY, THE UPDATE QUERY, THAT REFERS TO THE FIRST ONE
Dim UpdECStartRank2SQL As String
UpdECStartRank2SQL = "UPDATE tbl_TimeReporting INNER JOIN ECStart2SQL ON tbl_TimeReporting.[#] = ECStart2SQL.[#] SET tbl_TimeReporting.ECStart = [ECStart2SQL]![tsUpdated] WHERE (((tbl_TimeReporting.ECStart) Is Null) AND ((tbl_TimeReporting.Sequence)=2))"

'OPERATION
DoCmd.SetWarnings False
DoCmd.RunSQL UpdECStartRank2SQL
MsgBox "Done!", , "Done!"
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

End Sub
```

Please, if you can offer any help, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a query you use a CreateQueryDef command

```
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef

Set qdf = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("MyQuery", "SELECT * FROM Table1")
```

Now you can use the query in SQL commands like you normally would, for example

```
"UPDATE MyTable INNER JOIN MyQuery ON ..."
```

And to delete it you use QueryDefs.Delete

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs.Delete "MyQuery"
```

Comment: To add Marek,because he is running an action query, DAO.Recordset will not be needed. The original Update SQL in the OP's post will work instead.

Comment: Sure, I only meant that as an example. But I guess I should change it so it won't cause any confusion

Comment: this is excellent, my code works now and I am looking forward to learning more about this.  Thanks so much!!